# Glass GDK High frequency LiveCard Hello, World example?

Tags: android, google-glass, google-gdk

It seems like every tutorial that I can find has a different, usually old, way of doing it. For example, even Google's [LiveCard page](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/ui/live-cards) has an example where they tell you to implement [LiveCardCallback](https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/gdk/reference/com/google/android/glass/timeline/LiveCardCallback.html) , however the link they give is dead, and that class doesn't exist in the GDK.

I also found a gdk apidemo on github, but most of those examples seem to be outdated?

Any good resource for an Android developer just starting out on Glass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`LiveCardCallback` was renamed to `DirectRenderingCallback` in XE12. Thanks for catching one that we missed!

Third-party examples that you find online may have not yet updated to XE12, but the Compass, Stopwatch, and Timer on our [GitHub page](http://github.com/googleglass) (and also found in the add-on's samples folder) are all updated and good examples of using live cards with high-frequency direct rendering.